# Are there example Strings for unittests? (e.g. with control characters)

Tags: string, unit-testing

I have to write several unittests in a software of ours. In many ocasions I came across Strings which are Internally set/User set or even persisted (e.g. Database/XML etc.)

Does anyone know of a character-set or string(s) to do simple tests, whether input is equal to output?

I know how to test, my question regards what to test.

For numbers you e.g test values around 0 or - + numbers or if they're retrieved from a string, floating point numbers and integer numbers.

But for Text/String I'm not aware of standard sequences to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [Big List of Naughty Strings](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings) - sounds like it might be what you need!

> The Big List of Naughty Strings is an evolving list of strings which have a high probability of causing issues when used as user-input data.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. thanks a lot